# How to set custom adapter for multi select spinner?

Tags: android, spinner

Am having doubt i could not find any solution on this i need to set the value to spinner from sqlite record for multi select spinner but i could not see any sample for this so far what i have found is this adapter:

```
public class MultiSelectionSpinner extends Spinner implements
        DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener
{
    String[] _items = null;
    boolean[] mSelection = null;

    ArrayAdapter<String> simple_adapter;

    public MultiSelectionSpinner(Context context)
    {
        super(context);

        simple_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        super.setAdapter(simple_adapter);
    }

    public MultiSelectionSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        simple_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        super.setAdapter(simple_adapter);
    }

    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
        if (mSelection != null && which < mSelection.length) {
            mSelection[which] = isChecked;

            simple_adapter.clear();
            simple_adapter.add(buildSelectedItemString());
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Argument 'which' is out of bounds.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean performClick() {
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
        builder.setMultiChoiceItems(_items, mSelection, this);

        builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1)
            {

            }
        });


        builder.show();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void setAdapter(SpinnerAdapter adapter) {
        throw new RuntimeException(
                "setAdapter is not supported by MultiSelectSpinner.");
    }

    public void setItems(String[] items) {
        _items = items;
        mSelection = new boolean[_items.length];
        simple_adapter.clear();
        simple_adapter.add(_items[0]);
        Arrays.fill(mSelection, false);
    }

    public void setItems(List<String> items) {
        _items = items.toArray(new String[items.size()]);
        mSelection = new boolean[_items.length];
        simple_adapter.clear();
        simple_adapter.add(_items[0]);
        Arrays.fill(mSelection, false);
    }

    public void setSelection(String[] selection) {
        for (String cell : selection) {
            for (int j = 0; j < _items.length; ++j) {
                if (_items[j].equals(cell)) {
                    mSelection[j] = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void setSelection(List<String> selection) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mSelection.length; i++) {
            mSelection[i] = false;
        }
        for (String sel : selection) {
            for (int j = 0; j < _items.length; ++j) {
                if (_items[j].equals(sel)) {
                    mSelection[j] = true;
                }
            }
        }
        simple_adapter.clear();
        simple_adapter.add(buildSelectedItemString());
    }

    public void setSelection(int index) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mSelection.length; i++) {
            mSelection[i] = false;
        }
        if (index >= 0 && index < mSelection.length) {
            mSelection[index] = true;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Index " + index
                    + " is out of bounds.");
        }
        simple_adapter.clear();
        simple_adapter.add(buildSelectedItemString());
    }

    public void setSelection(int[] selectedIndicies) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mSelection.length; i++) {
            mSelection[i] = false;
        }
        for (int index : selectedIndicies) {
            if (index >= 0 && index < mSelection.length) {
                mSelection[index] = true;
            } else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Index " + index
                        + " is out of bounds.");
            }
        }
        simple_adapter.clear();
        simple_adapter.add(buildSelectedItemString());
    }

    public List<String> getSelectedStrings() {
        List<String> selection = new LinkedList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < _items.length; ++i) {
            if (mSelection[i]) {
                selection.add(_items[i]);
            }
        }
        return selection;
    }

    public List<Integer> getSelectedIndicies() {
        List<Integer> selection = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < _items.length; ++i) {
            if (mSelection[i]) {
                selection.add(i);
            }
        }
        return selection;
    }

    private String buildSelectedItemString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        boolean foundOne = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < _items.length; ++i) {
            if (mSelection[i]) {
                if (foundOne) {
                    sb.append(", ");
                }
                foundOne = true;

                sb.append(_items[i]);
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public String getSelectedItemsAsString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        boolean foundOne = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < _items.length; ++i) {
            if (mSelection[i]) {
                if (foundOne) {
                    sb.append(", ");
                }
                foundOne = true;
                sb.append(_items[i]);
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

In this model i could not set my custom object list to spinner which am populating from sqlite how can i make can anyone share any solutions please let me know am struggling with this!!

Comment: i think you need to call `setItems()` either passing array of string `String[]` (loaded from db) or a `List<String>`

Comment: can you share some snippet

Comment: ok i will, but after reading the question again, i felt i miss understood you,  so you want to fill the spinner with items from db/ or set selected of items in the spinner?

Comment: items from db as multselected items how can i do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on your request, find below the (might be) working code:

assume you have a method that loads data from db as array of string:
and you have a reference on a `MultiSelectionSpinner` object, called `multiSpinner`:

```
String items[] = myDbHelper.getSpinnerItems();
multiSpinner.setItems(items);
```

based on the class you have, this code should fill items in the spinner adapter

Comment: is it possible to to return array of string from db i usually return with list but array how to do this

Comment: Thank you so much Yazan i made it thanq so much for you help

Comment: @venkatraman good to hear that, note that there is another overload of setItems() that accepts List<String>, you can use it too

Comment: but i need to get id also

Comment: id of what? clarify more

Comment: am setting spinner value from sqlite where i need to set id as well as name but i cannot set id i need to customize to List<STRING> to List<Modelclass>

Comment: this requires some major changes: methods, variables, Data Types in `MultiSelectionSpinner` class

Comment: as a beginner i need some help

Comment: i can give you a guidance, but you have to try it yourself, and post a new question asking for help with it, you need to replace all `String` to `Modelclass` in `MultiSelectionSpinner `, and fix issues that appear, you need to understand what old code does, and fix it in a way to have same result using the `Modelclass`

Comment: instead of this can i use multiselect listview with onclick edittext

Comment: sorry, i am not sure if you can